# Creating SurfaceView cause short screen blink

Tags: java, android, view

When I create `SurfaceView` for first time since app launch, the app screen blinks black for small time (about 1/4 second). It blinks over UI, so its really visible and doesn't look nice at all.
I've tried to comment all of my code in `surfaceCreated`, but effect is same, so problem is not here. How do I remove or "hide" this screen blink?

In activity:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
layout.addView(new Surface(getApplicationContext())); // causes short screen black blink
```

Surfaceview class:

```
public class Surface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
        public Surface(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
 
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
            setFocusable(true);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
              ... stuff
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after 2 hard-thinking days I've found quite a good workaround. Didn't fixed that blink, but it's hidden very well. Here's how to:

Create another Surfaceview class, for example FakeSurfaceview.java. Keep same options for it as I mentioned in SF class in main post. In surfaceCreated, add `this.setVisibility(GONE);`

In you main layout (first layout when your app launches), create `RelativeLayout` with width and height 0dp.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/setupRelative"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

At app start, after you set view to your main layout, create this fake Surfaceview:

```
RelativeLayout setupLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.setupRelative);
setupLayout.addView(new FakeSurfaceview(getApplicationContext()));
```

That's it. Now, creating this `FakeSurfaceview` will blink, but nobody will notice it because it'll create durring app start (best with combination of startup black activity color!). Then, when you create anytime another `SurfaceView`, no blink will apear. That's it!